# DevOps Server Activation

Tags: azure-devops, activation, azure-devops-server

We are running a trial version of the DevOps server on-premise. I'm trying to activate it so we aren't on the trial version any more.

Our company developers each have a VisualStudio Enterprise subscription, my understanding of this page:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/

is that if we have the Enterprise subscriptions (which we get via partner status) then we get one server license as well as a user license.

"Visual Studio subscriptions include one server license plus a user CAL for the subscriber."

If this is not the case, can someone explain? If this is the case, how do I go about activating DevOps server to not be in free-trial status?

Comment: See [this](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing-details/), the normal VS Enterprise subscriptions should contain the service license and user license.

Comment: Thanks, I was fairly confident that our case was covered license wise and this would seem to confirm it however, I'm still searching for an answer as to how I actually make use of our licenses to remove the 'trial' status or 'activate' DevOps server if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm still searching for an answer as to how I actually make use of our
>   licenses to remove the 'trial' status or 'activate' DevOps server if
>   you will.

You can check [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/team-foundation-server-update-2-trial/). Apart from earlier versions of tfs, it also applies to Azure Devops Server 2018 and 2019.

Open `Team Foundation Server Administration Console` and double-click the server name, you would see a window like this:

[image]

Click `Complete Trial` and you can **remove the trial status** in TFS Web UI. I think that's what you want.

**And about license:**

*Starting with Update 2, you will not need to enter a product key into any version of TFS. If you download TFS from www.visualstudio.com, however, there will continue to be a trial experience. This experience is only there to help you comply with our server and user licensing requirements. You can opt out of it up front, at any point during the trial, or even after it expires. Critically, your server will continue working even if you let your trial expire. When you complete the trial, or when it expires, you need to ensure that you have a valid license in order to remain compliant.*

So you can continue to use that in normal work since as you mentioned above the developers in your team each have one VS Enterprise subscription. (More details about licensing see [licensing whitepaper](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=13350))

Comment: Ok! I was under the assumption that when I clicked 'Complete Trial' I had to link my VS Enterprise account up somehow for verification, this was not the case. I also recently got a reply back through the support channels and they too verified that you can complete the trial without any keys being inputted etc. Many thanks for the assistance.